# How to access a pouchdb in electron from external app?

Tags: ipc, electron, pouchdb

TLDR; What's the best way to access the pouchdb from outside electron?

I've built an electron app with a pouch database. Now I have another small C# tray app to interface with a fingerprint reader. It is working, but I would like to use the same database for both apps.

Or is there a better way to do 2way communication between the apps? I already communicate with the fingerprint-reader-app using a basic API endpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can drop in an `express-pouchdb` layer on top of your PouchDB Electron app, which will allow it to communicate with other apps via HTTP. Here's a video where I demonstrate how you can use this to sync two separate PouchDBs running in Node: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5iTzm8sTtd4

Comment: how to backup database locally in express-pouchdb ?